# croppie js image size of uploaded image is 7-8 times then orignal image

Tags: javascript, jquery, croppie

I have implemented croppie js in my application with following configuration.

```
var uploadconfig = {
 imgw: "360",
 imgh: "240",
 type:"square",
 upid:"id_upload",
 displaydiv:"imgupdiv",
 act:"saveimage",
 imgsize:"large"
};


$uploadCrop = $('#shoimgupload-demo').croppie({
enableExif: true,
viewport: {
    width: uploadconfig.imgw,
    height: uploadconfig.imgh,
    type: uploadconfig.type
},
boundary: {
    width: 500,
    height: 400
}
});
```

but after uploading image the final image gets resized to bigger size.
say i have uploaded png image with size 9kb it gets converted to 60kb after successful upload.

i have read in few articles that adjusting quality param can control quality and size of image but no change getting happened.
Can anyone help me on this?

Or anyone know the ratio of image resize will be appreciated.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but did you find a solution to this?